# Unable to Post in Angular / Express

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, express

I am trying to post using angular but keep getting a 404 error. It looks like the request is not being made. Any ideas why? Thanks for all the help.

```
  var param = $scope.tag;
// client
  $http({method: 'Post', url: '/api', headers: {
  "Content-Type": "application/json", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" }, data: {tag: param}})
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    });

// server
app.post('/api', function (req, res) {
  var tag = req.body.tag;
  request("http://food2fork.com/api/search?key=KEY&q=" + tag, function (req, res) {
    res.json(response);
  });
});

// request headers
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:17
Content-Type:application/json
Host:localhost:3000

// response headers
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:22
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Sat, 19 Sep 2015 23:22:15 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Powered-By:Express
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not have to use all that code. Try:

```
// Client:
var tag = $scope.tag;

$http.post('/api', {tag: tag})
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});

//Server:
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/api', function(req, res) {
  var tag = req.body.tag;
  res.send(tag);
});
```

Comment: I have tried your code and I get this error: POST http://localhost:3000/api net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Also, my request headers show this: Provisional headers are shown

Answer (score 1):

Use `method: 'POST'` instead of `method:'Post'`.

The latter is not recognized and a default GET is emitted instead that the POST you expect.

**edit: checked the code and what I wrote above is not true**

In addition to that...shouldn't be some URL like

```
/api/tags
```

???

Comment: I changed it to 'POST' but I still get the 404 error. The purpose of this is so I could grab the params and use it on the server.

Comment: Can you post the request info from developer tools?

Comment: Were you looking for the response headers? I updated the post to show both.

Comment: No I was looking for something like 'POST: http://localhoat:3000/...'. And please post also the server side code that you used. Something like 'app.post (...)'

Comment: POST http://localhost:3000/api net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
b @ angular.js:10661
q @ angular.js:10480
d.$get.g  @ angular.js:10187
(anonymous function)  @ angular.js:14634
a.$get.n.$eval  @ angular.js:15916
a.$get.n.$digest  @ angular.js:15727
a.$get.n.$apply @ angular.js:16024
(anonymous function)  @ angular.js:23416
c @ angular.js:3293

I also edit the post with server side code.

Comment: Is there something I could do to check?

Now the request headers is showing: Provisional headers are shown

Comment: From your log it seems that a get is issued instead of a post. Try $http.post (...) like the first answer suggests

Comment: Also did you noticed that you are using the variable 'response' instead of 'res' on the server code?

Comment: I did, I just cleaned it up. Thank you! I tried the other code and i still get: Provisional headers are shown

Comment: That means that the browser is waiting for a response which is notn coming (I guess) are you sure that the link you are requesting on the server side works? I'm getting 403 not authorized when hitting http://food2fork.com/api/search?key=KEY&q=something

Comment: Its not working for you because you need an api key. I'm certain it works. I just tried it in Postman.

Comment: If I were you I would try to put a log in the callback, just to make sure.